# Is there a way to get the modified data from within a EEx template

Tags: elixir, plug

I'm using EEx template engine to render HTML pages (no Phoenix here). I'm passing the connection (`Plug.Conn`) `conn` to the template along with extracted parameter list (`params`) and the session map (`session`)  with : `body = EEx.eval_file(path, conn: conn, params: conn.params, session: session)`. `params` and `session` are provided just for convenience as they also are in the connection.

If the page modifies the session (configured with cookies), say with something like `<% Plug.Conn.put_session(conn, "reply", 42) %>`), this modifies the connection but this also remains local to the page and is not propagated.

Is there a way to retrieve this modified version of the connection from the EEx engine ?

NB: I'm talking about the connection (`Plug.Conn`), but it could be any variable that is modified or created by the template engine, just a similar way `Code.eval_string("a=1\n b=2\n c=a+b")` does : `{3, [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EEx.eval_file` and `EEx.eval_string` both return a `String` type, they do not return the updated bindings (as, like you say, `Code.eval_string` does).

I think the reasoning behind this is that you want a `render` function to have no side-effects (like database calls or session modification).

You don't want business-logic in your templates, you want to put that in your controller or data layer (with the advantage that you can test it in isolation).

<sub>Maybe offtopic, but if you're coming from a PHP background (where you can put all your code in one file that looks like an HTML template) this might be the source of the confusion.</sub>

### Update

This could work though:

```
quoted = EEx.compile_string("<%= c = a + b %>")
{result, bindings} = Code.eval_quoted(quoted, [a: 1, b: 2])

Keyword.fetch(bindings, :c) # {:ok, 3}
```

Comment: I know this and I agree with you. I'm not talking about side effects on `conn` but to get an updated copy of it once it had passed through the EEx engine, just as it happens when it passes through a plug

Comment: Clever! And this also show how elixir is a powerful language. Thanks.